# Rails 3.2.1 template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates

I get the following error message:

```
Template is missing
Missing template dishes/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],      :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/restaurant/app/views"
```

In my `dishes_controller`:

```
def show
    @dish = Dish.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html # show.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @dish }
     end
end
```

The template is not missing. It's located under `app/views/dishes/show.html.erb`

Output of `C:\Sites\restaurant>rake routes`:

```
    root     /                       static_pages#home
    dishes GET    /dishes(.:format)          dishes#index
    POST   /dishes(.:format)          dishes#create
    new_dish GET    /dishes/new(.:format)      dishes#new
    edit_dish GET    /dishes/:id/edit(.:format) dishes#edit
    dish GET    /dishes/:id(.:format)      dishes#show
    PUT    /dishes/:id(.:format)      dishes#update
    DELETE /dishes/:id(.:format)      dishes#destroy
    help        /help(.:format)            static_pages#help
    about        /about(.:format)           static_pages#about
    contact        /contact(.:format)         static_pages#contact
    menu        /menu(.:format)            static_pages#menu
```

Comment: Are the other views like `new`, `edit` views working?

Comment: If the file is there, only thing comes to my mind is that Rails can't read the file! please check the permission!

Comment: new and edit are working.  the index function is also working.  I was able to create a Dish as well.

Comment: You should check permissions on the file and then also try stopping and starting your server, just to make sure.

Comment: Can you post the output of rake routes?

Comment: Permissions are good.  Same as other files in views/dishes folder.  I've restarted the server several times.

Comment: I don't think there is any url problem, since it is going to controller.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit history of how this project was created? if you create a new application in same way does it have the same problem? Also did you tried restarting your server?

Comment: Re-created the application and the problem is no longer there.  Must have been some bug with my system.  First time coding rails in windows and am not all that comfortable with it yet.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Like others have suggested, it's probably permissions. I occasionally run into issues like this with Vagrant, and have to restart my Vagrant session to get things back to normal.

Since you're just in Windows, I would right click on the file, make sure it isn't read only or set to anything insane, restart your web server and give it another look.